# Add invisible tab to App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs

I have a Tab App with 3 tabs. The tab view controllers all link to the Tab Bar Controller.

However, I don't necessarily need a 4th tab, but, I need a hidden view that the user can only access by clicking a button on another view.

How should I go about doing this?

Usually, I create a view controller and create a relationship to the tab bar controller and set the view controller class.

However I do not want to see a fourth tab for the hidden view.

Note that the fourth view should still be showing the tab bar when it is loaded and visible.

Thanks

Comment: Is this button (or buttons) to show the 4th controller in one specific controller, or in multiple controllers?

Comment: @rdelmar It will be in 1 specific one; Main Menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by making the 4th controller a child view controller of MainMenu. You can do something like this in your button method:

```
    self.vc4 = [[FourthViewController alloc] init]; // or some other way to instantiate your controller
    [self addChildViewController:self.vc4];
    [self.vc4 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.vc4.view];
    self.vc4.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

vc4 would be a strong property of type FourthViewController.

Comment: @Milo, yes it should, since your setting its frame to the bounds of MainMenu's view, which should be the correct size to show the tab bar.